# Swagger url is not working after migration from springfox swagger to openAPI

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am having springfox swagger2 where http://localhost:8080/context/swagger-ui.html works fine.
Now I have modified all the changes to make it open-api runnable.
Using : [Migrating from springfox swagger2 to springdoc openapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291371/migrating-from-springfox-swagger2-to-springdoc-openapi)

Now I can open my service definition json by using group name like below:

http://localhost:8080/context-path/v3/api-docs/groupName

but unable to open swagger-ui.html like what i had earlier with springfox 2.0

Can you help me,how to open & what should be the url?
when I type  http://localhost:8080/context/swagger-ui.html, it's creating new route like below & not opening anything,404 error.

http://localhost:8080/context/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/context/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

Please note ,I have added swagger-ui.html in my project as it's added already for swagger 2.0

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
```

Please help to get swagger home screen so that I can test rest services

Comment: pls help.......

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that Swagger-UI is exposed at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

If you want that Swagger-UI should be under the context root, update the following property in `application.properties` file or it's equivalent.

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/your-context-path/swagger-ui.html
```

The list of properties can be found [here](https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties)